# miniLZO compression algorithm build error on MSP430

Tags: c, msp430, lzo

I am trying to run the LZO compression algorithm on an MSP430FR5994 launchpad.
The version I choose is 2.06.

The program I run is `testmini.c`, which is an example code for the algorithm.
Here is the error message and corresponding code snippet.

```
LZO_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT_HEADER(sizeof(lzo_uintptr_t) >= sizeof(lzo_voidp))

"../minilzo.c", line 1982: error #95: the size of an array must be greater than zero

static unsigned char __LZO_MMODEL in  [ IN_LEN ];
static unsigned char __LZO_MMODEL out [ OUT_LEN ];
.
.
.
static HEAP_ALLOC(wrkmem, LZO1X_1_MEM_COMPRESS);
"../main.c", line 31: error #96: array is too large
```

I found a similar issue on the TI forum. I change Code Composer Studio compiler from `T1 v21.6.0.LTS` to `GNU v9.3.0.31 (Mitto Systems Limited)`

[TI forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/code-composer-studio-group/ccs/f/code-composer-studio-forum/60134/the-size-of-array-must-be-greater-than-zero)

After change the compiler, the code build and load to lauchpad successfully.
The program using miniLZO(LZO) algorithm need to call `lzo_init()` first.
It failed to run `lzo_init()` on my launchpad, which mean the return of `lzo_init()` is not `LZO_E_OK`.

```
if (lzo_init() != LZO_E_OK)
{
    printf("internal error - lzo_init() failed !!!\n");
    printf("(this usually indicates a compiler bug - try recompiling\nwithout optimizations, and enable '-DLZO_DEBUG' for diagnostics)\n");
    return 3;
}
```

In the `README.LZO` file:

```
 If you are running on a very unusual architecture and lzo_init() fails then
 you should first recompile with '-DLZO_DEBUG' to see what causes the failure.
 The most probable case is something like 'sizeof(void *) != sizeof(size_t)'.
 After identifying the problem you can compile by adding some defines
 like '-DSIZEOF_VOID_P=8' to your Makefile.

 The best solution is (of course) using Autoconf - if your project uses
 Autoconf anyway just add '-DMINILZO_HAVE_CONFIG_H' to your compiler
 flags when compiling minilzo.c. See the LZO distribution for an example
 how to set up configure.ac.
```

I don't know how to `"enable '-DLZO_DEBUG' for diagnostics"`, and don't know how to apply the solution mentioned in the `README.LZO` to Code Composer Studio compiler.

I hope someone knows how to solve it. Thank you very much.